# SQL Server max memory setting

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

Physical memory is `32GB`.

SQL Server 2008 R2 max memory setting is 29000(MB).

When I check the task manager `sqlservr.exe` uses over `29GB`.

I am not sure why?

Comment: what does this query say `sys.dm_os_process_memory `

Answer (score 1):

you should not use task manager ,to see memory usage for SQLServer..

TaskManager doesn't report memory used by AWE(for 32 bit sql server) and locked pages(for 64 bit sql server)..

To see exact memory usage,use..

```
select * from sys.dm_os_process_memory
```

or

```
select * from sys.dm_os_performance_counters where counter_name like 'total%memory%'
```

References and further reading:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35418/why-is-sql-server-memory-showing-in-task-manager
http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jonathan_kehayias/archive/2009/08/24/troubleshooting-the-sql-server-memory-leak-or-understanding-sql-server-memory-usage.aspx